# Build bar chart in Vega with different colors for negative and positive values

Tags: bar-chart, data-visualization, vega

So I need to build something like this using Vega library:

[image: Bar chart with different colors for positive/ negative values]

Now, I'm a super n00b, so please have mercy.

First solution: use some sort of conditional formatting (like in Excel): if bar value < 0, make it red. If bar value > 0, make it green. I could find some conditional syntax for Vega-Lite, which gave me hope, but how do I translate the syntax to normal Vega, I have no clue.

Second, I thought about using some color scheme for ranges, like the ones that have a threshold. But I got completely confused about what scale range type to use, and noticed there is a relationship between scale range type and color schemes, so yeah. Confused.

Then, my colleague suggested this: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/layer_bar_annotations

So in the example, we can see that the value of the bar above the threshold has conditional formatting. So I tried filtering the data to obtain 2 subsets: `values_lower_than_0` and `values_higher_than_0` use them as sources for marks. But it seems like I don't know how to filter. My data looks like this:

```
[
  { "date": "2018-12-10", "difference": 20 }, 
  { "date": "2018-10-21", "difference": -10 }
  ...
]
```

So then I apply a transform on it:

```
...

{
      'name': 'values_lower_than_0',
      'source': 'temps',
      'transform': [{ 'type': 'filter', 'expr': 'datum.difference.Value < 0' }]
}
```

But when I use the `values_lower_than_0` in the marks nothing seems to be happening.

So, I have 2 questions:

- Is this the best approach to build such a chart? (Tbh, it seems pretty convoluted to me).
- If yes, then how am I supposed to get the two data sets and use them to obtain the correct colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be the one where transforms on the dataset are not applied.

Taking the example from [here](https://uat.gramener.com/vega/chart/chart?chart=positive-negative-bars)

The idea is to set the `y2` value as mid of `Height`. `y` will then adjust based on whether the value is negative or positive to below midHeight or above midHeight, respectively. Please refer to `rect` type marks config below.

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v4.json",
  "width": 600,
  "height": 360,
  "autosize": "fit",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "url": "https://uat.gramener.com/vega/chart/data/pos-neg-items.json"
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {
        "data": "table",
        "field": "category"
      },
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 0.2,
      "round": true
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "domain": {
        "data": "table",
        "field": "amount"
      },
      "nice": true,
      "range": "height"
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "bars",
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {
        "data": "table"
      },
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {
            "scale": "xscale",
            "field": "category"
          },
          "width": {
            "scale": "xscale",
            "band": 1
          },
          "y": {
            "scale": "yscale",
            "field": "amount"
          },
          "y2": {
            "signal": "scale('yscale', 0)"
          },
          "fill": {
            "signal": "datum['amount'] > 0 ? '#5CB38B' : '#E6685C'"
          },
          "tooltip": {
            "signal": "datum"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "item_score",
      "type": "text",
      "from": {
        "data": "table"
      },
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {
            "scale": "xscale",
            "field": "category"
          },
          "y": {
            "scale": "yscale",
            "field": "amount"
          },
          "dy": {
            "signal": "datum['amount'] > 0 ? -4 : 14"
          },
          "dx": {
            "signal": "bandwidth('xscale')/2"
          },
          "align": {
            "value": "center"
          },
          "fill": {
            "value": "black"
          },
          "text": {
            "field": "amount"
          },
          "fontSize": {
            "value": 12
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "item_name",
      "type": "text",
      "from": {
        "data": "table"
      },
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {
            "scale": "xscale",
            "field": "category"
          },
          "dx": {
            "value": 20
          },
          "dy": {
            "signal": "datum['amount'] > 0 ? height/2 + 14 : height/2 - 6"
          },
          "align": {
            "value": "center"
          },
          "fill": {
            "value": "#000000"
          },
          "text": {
            "field": "category"
          },
          "fontSize": {
            "value": 12
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I love this, way nicer. This is more or less what I was looking for, a conditional fill.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so tired, I make stupid mistakes today! If somebody wants to use the third approach described above, then I was correct, I was just passing the wrong source name to the mark.

Another remark would be: you only need to calculate one subset, for the negative values (for example `values_lower_than_0`).

Once you do that, you'll have a mark called `bars` for all bars (like a default, with a green fill). The data source for this mark will be the default data. On top of that mark, you will apply a second mark, called `negative_bars` (for example), whose source will be `values_lower_than_0` and you'll give it a red fill.

My question regarding the best approach still stands.